# Setting a value inside an array

Tags: php

If I want to add a value in an array, I can use:

```
$array[] = 'value'; // or...
array_push($array, 'value');
```

If I want to set the value associated with a key, I can use:

```
$array['key'] = 'value';
```

Is there any function I could use instead of the `[]` syntax?

Comment: What's your goal? Even if the key value is variable, the array accessor takes a variable like `$array[$keyValue]`.

Comment: Why do you need a function when a simple assignment will do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make your own?

```
function setArrayValue(&$array, $key, $value) {
   $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason need a function to do it you could write your own:

```
function array_push_key(&$array, $key, $value) {
    $array[$key] = $value;
}
```

Not sure why you would need that though

Answer (score 0):

They're right you need to write your own function

```
 function arrayValue(&$array, $key, $value){
      $array[$key] = $value;
 }
```

Then you can call this via

```
 arrayValue($array, $key, $value);
```

But if your array is not an associative array, it is always better to use

```
 $array[] = $value;
```

Then you can call this through

```
 $array[0]; //and so on.....
```